# Wacom CTL-480-S detected but not properly working

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce, tablet, wacom

I have been struggling for the past three days trying to configure the aforementioned tablet using xsetwacom commands grouped in shell scripts and it works almost perfectly, aside from the fact that the four ExpressKeys present on the tablet itself won't work in any way. Here's what i've done:

- Installed the *input-wacom* kernel driver.
- Installed the *xf86-input-wacom* xorg driver.
- Rebooted.
- I ran `xsetwacom list devices` and it detected all i needed: the pad, the eraser and the stylus.

  ```
   Wacom Intuos S Pad pad             id: 10  type: PAD       
   Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus          id: 11  type: STYLUS    
   Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser          id: 13  type: ERASER
  ```
- I configured parameters such as area and button shortcuts via shell commands and scripts with `xsetwacom`.

`lsusb`, `dmesg` and `xinput list` show normal output, saying that the pad is detected, but then with the steps taken above configuring an ExpressKey, for example with a command such as this `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 1 "key +a"` i see no errors printed to the shell but pressing the button on the tablet does not print an `a` character on any text-based application. After a lot of surfing the net, yesterday i got it to work by doing `sudo modprobe wacom && sudo modprobe wacom_w8001`, but that was definitely not the solution to my problem, as rebooting the machine afterwards gave me unresponsive buttons again, and right now reproducing that step is ineffective, button presses are not even reported by `xev`.

Also, here are two of the scripts i use to configure the tablet on-the-fly for the different applications i use.
`wacom_gimp`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set up the area to use the whole tablet
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" area 0 0 15200 9500

#Set up the stylus buttons
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 1 1
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 2 2
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 3 "key +ctrl +z"

#Set up the ExpressKeys
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 3 "key +p"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 1 "key +n"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 8 "key +a"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 9 "key +shift +e"
```

`wacom_osu`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set up the area to be less than 1/4 of the tablet.
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" area 9000 0 15200 3750

#Set up the stylus buttons
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 1 1
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 2 5
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" button 3 4

#Set up the ExpressKeys
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 3 "key +ctrl +r"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 1 "key +f5"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 9 "key +f8"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" button 8 "key +f9"
```

*Am i missing anything in my setup? Is there anything wrong in my course of action? I followed the steps in the [Linux Wacom Tablet Project Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/wiki/?source=navbar). I've also looked at [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1780154), but applying patches and compiling from source gave me compilation errors, so i gave up.*